ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput' after using PyInstaller
I used the keyboard listener from the pynput.keyboard library and when I import it to my project: it works. When I run it to PyInstaller it gives me an error like this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "hack\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pynput import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'
[16912] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception

I used the --hidden-imports tag in my auto-py-to-exe program. It still doesn't work. Here is the code of me using pynput
hack/init.py
import json
import os
from pynput import keyboard
import pyautogui
import pytesseract
import _thread
from .window import *
from time import sleep
from openai import OpenAI
import pyscreenshot

Using the keyboard listener
starting=False
    def on_press(key):
        global starting
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            starting=False
    
    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
    listener.start()

The way I know what the error is: I ran it from the console so that I can see debug what was the errors. This is one of the errors that showed up.

Are you sure that you have activated your virtual environment (venv) when running the script? Or otherwise have correctly installed pynput globally?

I used auto-py-to-exe to do the command for me. I recently tried to use it in the console but still no luck. It also gives me the same problem when I have BeautifulSoup so apparently it also doesn't work when I try to use PyInstaller even with the tag of --hidden-imports. If you have another solution, maybe try reaching me out in discord. My username is beronicous.
